# Relations between Table and View using Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

Is there a natural option to establish a relationship between table and view or i should use trigger as a workaround to check that the data consistency?

I have a lookup view (for some reason i need it to be view and not a table).
I want to insert records to a different table. one of the values of the record i want to insert MUST be one of the ids from the lookup view.

For example:

ViewCities (CityId, CityName) -- This is the lookup View. the table behind the view located on a different database.
now i want to insert new row to tblUsers. one of the row columns is CityId. I want that not one will be able to insert a row to tblUsers that includes cityid that not exists on ViewCities.

Comment: Is the view on the table? In which case you woundn't need to check at all.

Comment: Show us some database schema so we can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: From the fact that you tagged the question with "foreign-key-relationship", I assume there is a relationship between two tables? I don't think there is enough information to answer your question. Can you post the CREATE statement of the tables/views and show what the relationship is supposed to be?

Comment: Thanks for asking me to clarify my question. I have a lookup view (for some reason i need it to be as view and not as table).I want to insert records to a different table. one of the values of the record i want to insert MUST be one of the ids from the lookup view. Thanks.

Comment: Just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You have two options that I am aware of to maintain referential integrity. You cannot use a foreign key constraint because you said that the tables are in two separate databases. The options are:
1. Use triggers, as you had mentioned.
2. Use a check constraint which references a user defined function which does the check.

For example:

Let's say I have a database named test, and another database is the Northwind database. In my test database I want to create a table which records names of users. The check I want to enforce is that the user name must be one of the LastName's of a user in the Northwind database. I first create a UDF like so:

```
create function chk_name (@name varchar(50))
returns bit
as
begin
declare @name_found bit=0
if exists(select * from Northwind..Employees where LastName=@name)
    begin
        set @name_found=1
    end

return @name_found 
end
```

Then, I create the table with a check constraint like so:

```
create table tst
(name varchar(50) check ( dbo.chk_name(name)=1   )
)
```

Now, if you try to insert a row into the tst table, it must be one of the Last Names of the Employees table in the Northwind database.

Comment: You can just as easily use a view, instead of a table in the user defined function, by the way.